# parametric and symbolic nonlinear system

Tags: matlab, math, parameters

I am trying to solve the following system

```
(X-Psi.*sin(xi)).^2+(Y).^2-Theta.^2=0
(sin(xi).^2).*(1-X.^2-Y.^2)-((Theta./Psi).*cos(gamma)+Y.*cos(xi)).^2=0
```

My variables are `X` and `Y`. `Psi`, `xi`, `Theta`, `gamma` are parameters.

I try the following in Matlab:

```
syms gamma Psi xi Theta;
syms X Y;
sol=solve((X-Psi.*sin(xi)).^2+(Y).^2-Theta.^2==0,(sin(xi).^2).*(1-X.^2-Y.^2)-((Theta./Psi).*cos(gamma)+Y.*cos(xi)).^2==0);
```

but I get an error message:

> Reference to non-existent field 'X'.

Would you help?

Comment: The three lines run without an error.

Comment: yes it run but when I want the X solution, it give the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a solution for `X` tell `solve` to return it. You have to set the `vars` parameter:

```
sol=solve((X-Psi.*sin(xi)).^2+(Y).^2-Theta.^2==0,(sin(xi).^2).*(1-X.^2-Y.^2)-((Theta./Psi).*cos(gamma)+Y.*cos(xi)).^2==0,[X,Y])
```